# What should our domain be?

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name gamdev.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

Post your ideas for a **dot-com domain name** for this website, which captures the spirit and intent of the site, namely:

> {name} is intended for expert and advanced gamers on all consoles and computers, including, but not limited to...
>
> - Game Design
> - Game Programming
> - Asset Creation
> - Writing for Games
>
> …

Please follow these guidelines:

- **Check to see if the domain is taken <strike>or squatted</strike> *before* making the name suggestion.** <strike>Squatted and</strike> taken names, however clever, are not helpful. You can use [whois.net](http://www.whois.net) to check availability. (**EDIT:** Read [this post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/) regarding squatted names).
- **Post one domain per answer.** This makes the voting process much easier. If domains are very similar (e.g. "dev" and "devs"), they can be in the same answer.
- **Make sure the domain wasn't already suggested.** To search within this question, use a search query such as: `inquestion:1 "example.com"` replacing `example.com` with the domain to search for.
- **When coming back to this question, make sure to sort the answers "newest first"**, as to not miss new proposals.

Comment: Guess we should get started with that stuff here also :p

Comment: Use [bust a name](http://www.bustaname.com/) to generate domain names.

Comment: @Fire Bustaname only checks for 404 like content. I got a few false positives from it. Still pretty cool for thinking of stuff though.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897435.aspx ^^

Comment: Can we get a few game development domains that aren't programming-related? Coding is a relatively small part of the gamedev process, and I'd love to see some ideas that focus on the game part of things.

Comment: @ZorbaTHut Going to find thats what the bulk of the suggestions come from since this place spawned from a programming community.

Comment: Is finding a domain name still relevant? nothingtoinstall.com was only life for half a day before it was renamed back to webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm of the mind that gamedev.stackexchange.com is superior to all of the below suggestions, perhaps only short of my suggestion.  :)

Answer (score 37):

Beyond Polygons

## BeyondPolygons.com

Available.

Comment: I actually like this one a bunch. Stands out and is quite relevant.

Comment: This neatly nails my "something that isn't just about programming" request. It's game-related, without limiting itself to any particular genre or style of game - if anything, it explicitly avoids limiting itself to any particular style. I approve highly and would vote up multiple times if possible.

Comment: don't like it because it sounds like the site will be about 3D modelling to me. At least half the questions are about 2D games anyway.

Comment: Now registered by Stack Overflow! Looks like this will be our name :)

Comment: @Ricket: Registration does not indicate *acceptance* at all! I register any names that show momentum or promise. Carry on.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry. I didn't know you were actually preemptively registering domains, but I'm glad you are!

Comment: Seems to much driving on the graphics / 3D train to me. Games are not (only) that.

Comment: @Suma: That is what "beyond" is supposed to mean.

Comment: I am not native English speaker, hence my understanding is likely to be inaccurate. I understood Beyond like "the invisible background" (i.e. what makes polygons to be there).

Comment: I am not a fan of putting a 3D bent on the domain, either.

Comment: @Suma: beyond can mean "behind", or it can mean "in addition to". So in this case, "beyond polygons" can sort of mean "more than just polygons". You had the first or second definition, but it is implied to be the third: http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=beyond

Comment: This feels a bit too graphics oriented, however, the site is too programing oriented.  Maybe this will create some balance?

Comment: Dates the site.  Will be outdated when we render using nurbs.

Answer (score 15):

**GameTestPatch.com**

Play on Game, Set, Match. Maybe we don't have that many game developers who are also tennis players.

Comment: I think it's cute.

Comment: +1 I like it a lot!

Answer (score 9):

**TheGameLoop.com**

Comment: +1 Not taken, only problem is that people could type GameLoop.com instead.

Comment: I like it though I agree that simply GameLoop.com might be a better solution.

Comment: Yeah, but GameLoop.com has been taken already. They could try to buy it from them...

Comment: According to whois and some searching, [this](http://contrasttomediocrity.blogspot.com/) is the blog of gameloop.com's registrant. He also registered gameloop.net. According to the Wayback machine, it was a site for a "Gameloop, Inc." in 2001 but has been through various "coming soon" pages since May 2001. Asking might be worth a try.

Comment: @TomWij: gamedevs are the kind of usebase that would recover from that problem either by adding *the*, bookmark the site or use Google Chrome. ;P

Comment: it's a really great name but "the" in the beginning is not nice. It's probably to long but how about something like "brokengameloop.com" (not taken btw) which also keeps in spirit with stackoverflow and serverfault naming scheme.

Comment: -1 There is a game development conference held in boston called "Boston Game Loop" that actually has a pending trademark on Game Loop for conference purposes.  

I talked to the founders and they're not going to be dicks about it or anything, but it will present some confusion.

Comment: I didn't like this one at first, but I've changed my mind. It's sort of catchy, describes community, and is common to most game developers.. not bad. I would think that a site that's been coming soon for 10 years is probably dead in the water and thus probably has an owner who wouldn't be beyond selling it.

Comment: I'm very torn. It's a nice name but "The" being in the domain really makes me hesitate...

Comment: Reminds me of "thefacebook"

Comment: Downvoted in current form. GameLoop.com would be perfect for me, however domain availability is a problem.

Answer (score 6):

**BoundingBoxes.com**

Answer (score 6):

### InventingWorlds.com

Available (suggested since [CreatingWorlds.com was a good suggestion but turned out to be taken](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-our-domain-be/78#78))

Comment: +1 thanks for permutation :) it even sounds better to me

Answer (score 5):

From the classic game architecture functions `Update()` and `Draw()`, we could have:

## UpdateDraw.com

(Available)

Comment: And maybe the title could actually be Update();Draw(); or something?

Answer (score 4):

**InterestingDecisions.com**

From "gaming is a series of interesting decisions", a pretty common (if controversial) quote.

Answer (score 2):

**BadVertex.com**

It's a bit too 3D specific but it keeps in spirit with Stack Overflow and Server Fault.

Answer (score 2):

**GameBytes.com** (<del>available</del> squatted)

Comment: My only problem with this is that it sounds like another gaming/community site. I don't think a developer would look at it and expect it to be about game development. I could be wrong though.

Comment: This is [not available](http://www.whois.net/whois/GameBytes.com). (although it *is* for sale, so I guess it counts as squatted).

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that. I wonder if I misspelled it when I did the lookup.

Comment: You wouldn't be [the first](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-our-domain-be/78#78) here :-7

Answer (score 2):

Polygon Builders

## PolygonBuilders.com

Available.

Answer (score 2):

**WorldSpawners.com** ([Available](http://www.whois.net/whois/worldspawners.com))

Answer (score 1):

**WhenItsDone.com**

Squatted, but might be ok: [See blog.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/)

Answer (score 1):

**GameBits.com** (squatted)

I like bits, but only bytes is available.

Edit: I have moved GameBytes.com into its own answer.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/ Squatted names may be possible, but please put your suggestions in different answers so they can be voted on independently.

Answer (score 1):

**DevelopAGame**

available as .com, .net, .org, .info

Answer (score 1):

### DevelopingFun.com

We're having fun developing, as well as developing "fun" for the player. Pun-tastic!

[Seems to be available.](http://www.whois.net/whois/developingfun.com)

Other possible puns: MakingFun.com, MakingOurOwnFun.com, etc.

Answer (score 1):

### PushingPixels.com

([squatted](http://www.whois.net/whois/pushingpixels.com))

Answer (score 0):

**GameDevQuestions.com**

Not terribly unique, but it is available.

Answer (score 0):

## FirstPersonDeveloper.com

Available.

Answer (score 0):

### OnlyTheGame.com

Available.

<sub>Play on words since: 1) game development is such an epic task that its only approached by the brave and 2) to those who build games, the only thing that matters is the game.</sub>

Comment: 3) You _only_ lost _"The Game"_

Answer (score 0):

### pathsolvers.com

(Available)

Answer (score 0):

### SynthesizingReality.com

Available, sadly not super easy to spell esp. if you don't choose the American side of the s/z "debate."  But it does explain what we do.

Answer (score -1):

**GameDevScene.com** or **Game-Dev-Scene.com**

Both seem to be available.

Answer (score -1):

### [gameworkshop.com](http://gameworkshop.com)

Taken, but not used.

Comment: Would be confused with games-workshop, makers of Warhammer/40k and such.

Answer (score -1):

**DevDungeon.com** (Because of the o'so many game dungeons we have completed/made)

Comment: I don't like it, it could seem like a D&D site...

Answer (score -1):

### adventurevat.com

available

Answer (score -1):

**MeleeHeap.com**

Game related *melee* + Code related *Heaps*

Answer (score -2):

**InverseRoot.com** or maybe **InverseSquareRoot.com**

In homage to the famous [fast `InvSqrt()` function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) from Quake III Arena (and yes, 0x5f3759df.com is taken, but that's probably not most easily remembered/typed domain name anyway)

Comment: While I understand the reference, it doesn't exactly scream "Game Development" to the average game developer (or so I would think).

Comment: Cute, but impractical.

Answer (score -2):

**BrokenGameLoop.com**

Answer (score -2):

Level Too Hard

## LevelTooHard.com

Available.

Answer (score -2):

Fellow Robot

## FellowRobot.com

Available.

Answer (score -2):

Epic Effects

## EpicEffects.com

Available.

Answer (score -2):

<strike>**creatingworlds.com**</strike> Not available.

Comment: CreatingWorlds.com is not available. You linked to CreatingsWorlds (not nearly as good but, yes, that's available).

Comment: @Robert Cartaino♦: damn my typo... sorry and thanks for the correction

Answer (score -2):

## CodeInTheGame.com

Available.

Answer (score -2):

It's not a dot-com. So feel free to vote it down if you are very strict about that. But I think this is an awesome name:

### MakingTheGa.me

(available)

Answer (score -2):

6to8weeks.com

:P

Answer (score -2):

### BehindPolygons.com

or

### BehindThePolygons.com

available.

This is obviously a play on the [BeyondPolygons](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-our-domain-be/62#62) name.  I think that *behind* better describes game development than *beyond*.

Comment: I think Behind Polygons would imply that we are a community dedicated to 3D game development. (Our work is what's behind the polygon) as opposed to the Beyond meaning more than just polygons.

Answer (score -3):

**CollisionDetect.com**

Comment: This (and BoundingBoxes.com) just seem too specific to me. I don't think this is all about game implementation, it's also about design and the like. Many games don't even have collision detection of any kind.

Answer (score -3):

**GameDevExchange.com**

Comment: Let's please stay away from notions of Stack Exchange or especially Experts Exchange.

Comment: Why exactly should we stay away from notions of Stack Exchange? The notion here is not very direct, does not seem to be a problem to me.

Answer (score -3):

**WorldViewProjection.com**

As of right now, not taken.

Answer (score -3):

### makingitbreathe.com

available

Answer (score -4):

**AngryData.com**

:)

Comment: Would fit better with a database or data mining website.

Comment: Maybe, but it also resonates about 'issues' and has a fun note to it. Game development should be fun.

Answer (score -4):

**WhileDeveloping.com**

Comment: Doesn't indicate that it is about Game Development.

Comment: @TomWij yeah, but it was floating around up there and available so I just got it out :p

Answer (score -4):

**DetectingLeaks.com**

Available for sale.

Answer (score -4):

**PlightSimulator.com**

Answer (score -4):

**MMOGDC.com**

(Massively Multiuser Online Game Developer's Community)

Comment: MMORPG is a mistake of our society and needs to be put down. Let's not continue it.

Answer (score -4):

**TightenUpThoseGraphics.com**

Answer (score -4):

### byhumansforhumans.com

(available)

Answer (score -5):

**ItsDoneWhenItsDone.com**

Comment: Maybe just WhenItsDone.com could work. (http://www.3drealms.com/duke4/)

Comment: @TomWij: that's what I was referring to :) whenItsDone is squatted but it might be bought if liked...

Comment: WhenItsDone.com seems to be taken though, maybe WhenItIsDone.com?

Comment: @TomWij: That might still be ok, see [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/)

Comment: @TomWij: I made WhenItsDone.com a [separate suggestion](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-our-domain-be/41#41).

Answer (score -5):

**DevelUp**.ga [me]

Comment: DevelUp.com, DevelUp.net, DevelUp.org are taken; not unique, not .com.

Comment: It was a nice play on words though! Oh well. :-\

Answer (score -5):

**Game-Invaders.com**