# Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline

Tags: discussion

*We closed the [domain naming thread (click for details)](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-our-domain-be).*

Instead, **let's start with a killer "elevator pitch!"** Joel will be blogging about the elevator pitch approach to naming, but to get you started:

### The Elevator Pitch

This isn't as easy as it sounds. Imagine the user who will never read your FAQ and you have two seconds to grab their attention. It should be catchy but descriptive. It should be thoroughly clear but painfully concise. **Make every... word... count.**

Here are some creative examples:

- [Gawker](http://gawker.com/): Daily Manhattan media news and gossip. Reporting live from the center of the universe.
- [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/): The gadget guide. So much in love with shiny new toys, it’s unnatural.
- [Autoblog](http://www.autoblog.com/): We obsessively cover the auto industry.
- [DumbLittleMan](http://www.dumblittleman.com/): So what do we do here? Well, it’s simple. 15 to 20 times per week we provide tips that will save you money, increase your productivity, or simply keep you sane.
- [Needcoffee.com](http://www.needcoffee.com/): We are the Internet equivalent of a triple espresso with whipped cream. Mmmm…whipped cream.

### Use it as a Tagline

A shorter elevator pitch *can* be used as a tagline — something you can display in the header at the top of the page. If it doesn't fit, consider shortening it or creating a separate tagline. Here are some great examples:

- [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/): News for nerds. Stuff that matters.
- [Lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com/): Don’t live to geek, geek to live!
- [The Simple Dollar](http://www.thesimpledollar.com/): Financial talk for the rest of us.

### The Motto (don't forget your logo)

A logo begs for it own little, short tagline — like a motto. Maybe the tagline inspires the logo; Maybe it's the other way around. Mottos make good t-shirt, bumper stickers, and other marketing material. Either way, you'll recognize a good motto when you see it:

- Just do it.
- Think Different.
- The Uncola.
- Intel inside.
- Like a rock.
- The king of beers.

…and perhaps all this leads to a proper name and domain for your site… *eventually*. So let's start from the basics. **Come up with a killer elevator pitch, tagline, and/or motto!**

Comment: Should this be community wiki?

Comment: Yes, it should. Done.

Comment: What is this slogan nonsense? The rows of interesting questions and answers that greet visitors to the home page explain our purpose more clearly than any tagline!

Answer (score 7):

- Tagline: *gamedev.com* - Where game-makers go to level up.

(Alternately, game-builders, game-developers, etc). I don't have a pitch/motto, but thought I'd throw *something* out to get the ball rolling. :)

Answer (score 5):

BeyondPolygons - Dreaming worlds, building games

Comment: No polygons!  It dates the site.  This suggestion would be `BeyondSprites` or `SpritesNCola.com` if it were the late 80's / early 90's right now, which would sound old by the time Quake came out.

Comment: Don't care too much for Beyond<Anything>, but love the Dreaming worlds, building games.

Comment: [Here ya go - voxel raycasting](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/voxel-ray-casting,2423.html)

Answer (score 4):

BeyondPolygons - How games are made.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite Tagline ever for a game company is *"We create Worlds"*, but that is sadly [already taken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_Systems).

*"If you build it, they will play"* sounds cheesy as hell and maybe based on a fad/meme, so I don't think that works either.

Some taglines:

- Giving your Graphics Card a purpose
- And on the eighth day, We created Fun
- Immersion Overdrive
- Everything your parents think is evil
- Blending the finest Arts into a lasting Experience

Answer (score 0):

Name: BeyondPolygons (going with the flow here :))

Tagline: Some sites cover games. We cover game development.

Elevator Pitch: If you have any question about programming, designing, or otherwise making your game, we're your go-to site.

Answer (score 0):

The nuts and bolts of game development.

<sub>Mostly nuts.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

BeyondPolygons - Building worlds, one polygon at a time

Answer (score -1):

BeyondPolygons: Beyond the dream of game development and into the reality.

Answer (score -1):

Under the hood: Game design for developers

Answer (score -1):

gamedev - It’s all fun and games.   But mostly games...

Answer (score -2):

BeyondPolygons - "Good Game."

Answer (score -3):

bugfragger:  ( and then a tagline )